# Why is a default template function picked as a better match than its specialized version?

Tags: c++, templates, c++03

I have the following template member function:

```
template <class ParameterT>
typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_base_of<BaseOne, ParameterT>::value
                            || boost::is_base_of<BaseTwo, ParameterT>::value, void>::type
MyClass::doSomething(const boost::shared_ptr<ParameterT> &param);
```

Calling `doSomething(sharedPtrTo_derivedFromBaseOne)`, `doSomething(sharedPtrTo_derivedFromBaseTwo)` or `doSomething(sharedPtrTo_derivedFromBaseOneAndBaseTwo)` all work, calling it with any other parameter does not work, which is indeed what I want so far.

Now in the implementation of the above, I want two more calls: `doSomething_baseOne` and `doSomething_baseTwo`. They should obviously compile for all calls that made it so far (so my `shared_ptr` parameter is either a `BaseOne` derived or `BaseTwo` derived, or both). I thought of something like this:

```
template<class BaseOneDerived>
void doSomething_baseOne(const boost::shared_ptr<BaseOneDerived> &param);
{
    std::cout << "doing nothing BaseOne";
}

template<class BaseTwoDerived>
void doSomething_baseTwo(const boost::shared_ptr<BaseTwoDerived> &param)
{
    std::cout << "doing nothing BaseTwo";
}

//doSomething implementation:
{
    doSomething_baseOne(param);
    doSomething_baseTwo(param);
}
```

And the `doSomething_baseOne`, `doSomething_baseTwo` specializations:

```
template<>
void MyClass::doSomething_baseOne(const boost::shared_ptr<BaseOne> &param)
{
    std::cout << "doing something with BaseOne";
}

template<>
void MyClass::doSomething_baseTwo(const boost::shared_ptr<BaseTwo> &param)
{
    std::cout << "doing something with BaseTwo";
}
```

Now supposing I have this simple hierarchy:

`class A : public BaseOne {};`

`class B : public BaseTwo {};`

`class C : public BaseOne, public BaseTwo {};`

I'd like, for the following calls:

```
MyClass X;
X.doSomething(boost::shared_ptr(new A());
X.doSomething(boost::shared_ptr(new B());
X.doSomething(boost::shared_ptr(new C());
```

To receive the following output:

```
//for first call
doing something with BaseOne
doing nothing BaseTwo

//for second call
doing nothing BaseOne
doing something with BaseTwo

//for third call
doing something with BaseOne
doing something with BaseTwo
```

Instead, I receive the "doing nothing with" message 6 times (actually I haven't implemented the non-specialized versions so I'm really just receiving a link-time undefined reference, but you get the point).

So basically the compiler picks the default `doSomething_baseOne` and `doSomething_baseTwo` as better matches than the specialized versions. Why is that? And how can I overcome this to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the compiler instantiate the following templates:

```
template<>
void doSomething_baseOne(const boost::shared_ptr<A> &param)
{
std::cout << "doing nothing BaseOne";
}
template<>
void doSomething_baseTwo(const boost::shared_ptr<A> &param)
{
std::cout << "doing nothing BaseOne";
}
template<>
void doSomething_baseOne(const boost::shared_ptr<B> &param)
{
std::cout << "doing nothing BaseOne";
}
template<>
void doSomething_baseTwo(const boost::shared_ptr<B> &param)
{
std::cout << "doing nothing BaseOne";
}
template<>
void doSomething_baseOne(const boost::shared_ptr<C> &param)
{
std::cout << "doing nothing BaseOne";
}
template<>
void doSomething_baseTwo(const boost::shared_ptr<C> &param)
{
std::cout << "doing nothing BaseOne";
}
```

which are better template specialization than what you provided.

Do it this way, using enable_if trick:

```
template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<T,BaseOne>::value>
doSomething_baseOne(const boost::shared_ptr<T>& param){
   std::cout << "doing something baseOne";
}
template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of<T,BaseOne>::value>
doSomething_baseOne(const boost::shared_ptr<T>& param){
   std::cout << "doing nothing baseOne";
}
template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<T,BaseTwo>::value>
doSomething_baseTwo(const boost::shared_ptr<T>& param){
   std::cout << "doing something baseTwo";
}
template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of<T,BaseTwo>::value>
doSomething_baseTwo(const boost::shared_ptr<T>& param){
   std::cout << "doing nothing baseTwo";
}
```

Or this way, using tag dispatch:

```
template<class T>
doSomething_baseOne(const boost::shared_ptr<T>& param
      ,std::integral_constant<bool,true>){
   std::cout << "doing something baseOne";
}
template<class T>
doSomething_baseOne(const boost::shared_ptr<T>& param
      ,std::integral_constant<bool,false>){
   std::cout << "doing nothing baseOne";
}
template<class T>
doSomething_baseOne(const boost::shared_ptr<T>& param){
   doSmething_baseOne(param,
         std::integral_constant<
               bool,std::is_base_of<T,BaseOne>::value
                               >{});
}
template<class T>
doSomething_baseTwo(const boost::shared_ptr<T>& param
      ,std::integral_constant<bool,true>){
   std::cout << "doing something baseTwo";
}
template<class T>
doSomething_baseTwo(const boost::shared_ptr<T>& param
      ,std::integral_constant<bool,false>){
   std::cout << "doing nothing baseTwo";
}
template<class T>
doSomething_baseTwo(const boost::shared_ptr<T>& param){
   doSmething_baseTwo(param,
         std::integral_constant<
               bool,std::is_base_of<T,BaseTwo>::value
                               >{});
}
```

A better solution would be that you use concepts. And even cleaner, constexpr if (C++17).

Comment: Unfortunately there are no concepts in c++03 AFAIK. I was thinking I needed some more SFINAE but was not really sure how to do it. So basically SFINAE is the only solution whenever you need to request the compiler to pick the default template as a "last resort" ?

Comment: Their is an other solution called *tag dispatch*. This is sometime more readable than using enable_if SFINAE trick.

Comment: @TedyS. your question is a bit too broad, there are many factors that can impact overload resolution, e.g., you can use [only one enable_if](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/iX2ePOel7KCcg4nv), or you can use [tag-dispatching](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/huRJhu6wzbJGwEJg)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I now see what tag-dispatching means, so basically you're just adding an extra layer of indirection such that the correct overload is picked based on `is_base_of`, right?

Comment: @Oliv `std::integral_constant<bool,true>` is aliased as `std::true_type`, ditto false_type

Comment: @Oliv Actually I find @PiotrSkotnicki's SFINAE version much easier to comprehend. But yes, I was mainly interested in what other solutions exist only as a learning purpose, I already got the code working using the initial solution (will probably update to using only one `enable_if` though)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, true_type is c++14 I believe, Tedy S. compile under C++03!! So I try to be the most basic I can.

Comment: @Oliv `std::true_type` is from C++11, just like `std::enable_if` that you use, OP uses Boost.TypeTraits and compiles in C++03, the code I proposed to OP uses Boost, so..., what is your point ?

Comment: Yep, it compiles under c++03. Will accept your answer since it is basically the solution to my problem, although @PiotrSkotnicki improved it. You might add that to the answer if you want, Oliv. Thanks both of you!

Comment: @Tedy S. Take care when you use the version of Piotr, it is smart, but it work only when you have two disjunction, and it hide the big trouble with disjunction and SFINAE (that concepts-ts solves). As a general rule, when you write an overload using enable_if, you should first disable explicitly all others overloads. If you don't, the compiler will complain about ambigus call.

Comment: @Piotr, ok I may have been inconsistently pessimistic about true_type. I was thinking about changing the code, but finally I thought it was less readable, the aim being to show an example of tag dispatch, not to write the most elegant code.